# put a parameter in the servlet url

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, parameter-passing

I have this peace of code:

```
<%
ArrayList<Utente> lista=null;
try{
    lista= (ArrayList<Utente>)request.getAttribute("lista");
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
    if(lista!=null){                    
for(int i=0;i<lista.size();i++){                                                                                        out.print("<tr>");
                        out.print("<td>"+lista.get(i).getNome()+"</td>");
                        out.print("<td>"+lista.get(i).getCognome()+"</td>");
                        out.print("<td>"+lista.get(i).getPosizione()+"</td>");
                        out.print("<td>"+lista.get(i).getTelefono()+"</td>");
                        out.print("<td><img src='imm/view.png'>&nbsp"+
                                "<a href='' id='"+lista.get(i).getIdUtente()+"' class='view'>Vedi</a>&nbsp &nbsp" 
                                +"<img src='imm/mod.png'>&nbsp"+
                                "<a href='InfoUtente&id="+lista.get(i).getIdUtente()+"' id='"+lista.get(i).getIdUtente()+"' class='mod'>Modifica   </a>&nbsp &nbsp"+
                                 "<img src='imm/del.png'>&nbsp"+
                                "<a href='' id='"+lista.get(i).getIdUtente()+"' class='del' name='"+lista.get(i).getNome()+" "+lista.get(i).getCognome()+"'>Elimina   </a></td>");
                         }

                }
                        %>
```

What I want to do now is to call the servlet InfoUtente when I click on the link Modifica on a certain index. And so I want to pass the index parameter to the servlet. 
How can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as you did, except the query string must start with a `?` and not with a `&`:

```
<a href='InfoUtente?id="+lista.get(i).getIdUtente()
                   ^-- here
```

`&` is used to separate the parameters inside the query string. And it must be HTML-escaped. So if you had a second parameter to pass, you would need to generate the following URL:

```
<a href='InfoUtente?id=" + theId + "&amp;foo=bar"
```

Note that generating HTML from Java code is not a good practice. It leads to hard-to read, unmaintainable code. Scriptlets should be avoided. You should do that using JSTL tags and the JSP EL:

```
<c:forEach var="utente" items="${lista}">
    <tr>
        <td><c:out value="${utente.nome}"/></td>
        <td><c:out value="${utente.cognome}"/></td>
        <td><c:out value="${utente.posizione}"/></td>
        <td><c:out value="${utente.telefono}"/></td>
        <td>
           <img src="imm/view.png"/>&nbsp;
           <a href="" id="${utente.idUtente}" class="view">Vedi</a>
           &nbsp;&nbsp;
           <img src="imm/mod.png"/>&nbsp;
           <a href="<c:url value="InfoUtente">
                        <c:param name="id" value="${utente.idUtente}"/>
                    </c:url>" class="mod">Modifica</a>
           &nbsp;&nbsp;
           <img src="imm/del.png"/>&nbsp;
           <a href="" class="del" name="<c:out value="${utente.nome} ${utente.cognome}"/>">Elimina</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Note how the structure is much more readable. Also note that

- it's `&nbsp;` and not `&nbsp`
- you can't have several elements with the same ID. This is invalid.
- `<c:out>` allows escaping special characters. So if any of the attributes contains a `<` or a `>` or a `&` for example, it won't lead to invalid HTML (or worse: to an XSS attack)
- using `<c:url>` allows using absolute paths instead of relative paths without hard-coding the context path, and it URL-encodes the parameters.

Comment: thanks!!!! now it works.
I don't understand what you mean with the comment "Note that generating HTML from a servlet is not a good practice. It leads to hard-to read, unmaintainable code. You should do that using a JSP." I'm using JSP..

Comment: Then don't enclose all this in a scriptlet. Scriptlets should be avoided at all cost. I'll edit my answer to show you how this should be generated.

Answer (score 0):

write an java script function and call that function onClick (or onSubmit etc.) of the specific field change. Inside that function build a string like "page.html?param=value". and redirect the page to there.

Comment: you have placed the <% %> . So i guess this is a jsp page. servlet always runs in server. but the page (view) you are showing runs in client side browser. From there there's no way to call the servlet. you can send a request to the server and the web container will dispatch it and send it to specific servlet.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to do this with jsp as below and about the problem you mentioned you have to put ? to start query string and not &

Check the code below

```
<%
ArrayList<Utente> lista=null;
try{
lista= (ArrayList<Utente>)request.getAttribute("lista");
}catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
if(lista!=null){                    
for(Utente utente : lista){%>                                                                                               
<tr>
    <td><%=utente.getName()%></td>
    <td><%=utente.getCognome()%></td>
    <td><%=utente.getPosizione()%></td>
    <td><%=utente.getTelefono()%></td>
    <td>
          <img src='imm/view.png'>&nbsp
          <a href='' id='<%=utente.getIdUtente()%>' class='view'>Vedi</a>&nbsp &nbsp
           <img src='imm/mod.png'>&nbsp</a>
           <a href='InfoUtente?id=<%=utente.getIdUtente()%>' id='<%=utente.getIdUtente()%>' class='mod'>Modifica </a>&nbsp &nbsp
        <img src='imm/del.png'>&nbsp</a>  <!-- Here you have to put ? instead of & -->
         <a href='' id='<%=utente.getIdUtente()%>' class='del' name='<%=utente.getName()%>'>Elimina</a></td>
</tr>
<%}
}%>
```